# Missing custom workflow template in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I encounter problems trying to deploy custom workflows designed in SharePoint Designer 2013 on a SharePoint 2013 host. The steps I've taken are:

1. On SiteCollection1, create reusable list workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013, one activity: log a message to the history list.
2. Save the workflow and save it as a template
3. Upload the *.wsp template in the solutions gallery on SiteCollection2 and activate the feature

Result: then trying to add manually the workflow to a document library or a list, my template is not in the list of available templates. What am I missing?

Note: SharePoint 2013 installed on-premises, WF Manager is deployed and registered for both site collections. The workflow itself is a SharePoint 2013 workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after discovering that the master page file was referencing SP.Runtime.js and SP.Workflowservices.js ; I removed those references and everything works as expected